# Win32 LogonUser doesn't return "Domain Admins" group

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I've a server with AD installed. In this server I created a user and added him to the "Domain Admins" group.

In C#, I used the win32 function LogonUser and authenticated with the user added to the "Domain Admins" group. The authentication successed but when I retrieve all the groups using WindowsIdentity and IdentityReference I don't get the "Domain Admins" Sid.

Any idea why is that?

This is the code I'm using:

```
            if (LogonUser(username,
                domainName,
                password,
                (int)LogonType.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                (int)LogonProvider.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                ref logonToken) != 0)
            {
                WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(logonToken);
                foreach (IdentityReference oneGroup in wi.Groups)
                {
                    GroupList.Add(oneGroup.Value);
                }
                return err;
            }
```

Notice that oneGroup.Value holds the Sid of the group which the user is member of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an API call for this? You have `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` to do this:

```
// Vaidate credentials
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
}

// To get user groups
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName))
{
    return user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
}
```